# How to perform a failover with Netflix/Eureka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, failover, netflix-eureka

I use Eureka as my service discovery and as a load balancer, and it is working fine when having two instances of a service "A", however when I stop one of this instances Eureka doesn't recognize that one of the instances is down and it keeps me showing an error page everytime the load balancer tries to use the dead instance.

I have put the `enableSelfPreservation` to `false` to prevent that but it takes Eureka up to 3 - 5 minutes to unregister that service, however I want high availability over my service and I want to perform the failover immediately in a matter of seconds. Is this possible using Eureka, if not how can I achieve to use only the alive instances when the others are dead.

I am using spring boot, here is my configuration for the Eureka server.

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a ribbon configuration to your application.yml. It is also recommended to set the hystrix isolation level to THREAD with a timeout set.

Note: This configuration should be in the *client* side (this usually means your gateway server), since Ribbon (and Spring Cloud in general) are a form of client-side load balancing.

Here's an example that I use:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 40000 #Timeout after this time in milliseconds

ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 5000 #try to connect to the endpoint for 5 seconds.
  ReadTimeout: 5000 #try to get a response after successfull connection for 5 seconds
  # Max number of retries on the same server (excluding the first try)
  maxAutoRetries: 1
  # Max number of next servers to retry (excluding the first server)
  MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 2
```